# Missing amdgpu firmware

Tags: kali-linux, firmware, amd-graphics

Kali Linux system notifying that `amdgpu` firmware is missing but they are not available in git. I have been having some bugs while shutting down too, could be related or unrelated.

```
sudo update-initramfs -u

update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-kali5-amd64
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/vega10_cap.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sienna_cichlid_cap.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_cap.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/psp_13_0_11_ta.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/psp_13_0_11_toc.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/psp_13_0_10_ta.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/psp_13_0_10_sos.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_3_imu.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_4_rlc.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_4_mec.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_4_me.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_4_pfp.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_3_rlc.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_3_mec.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_3_me.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_3_pfp.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_0_toc.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sdma_6_0_3.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sienna_cichlid_mes1.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sienna_cichlid_mes.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_mes.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_3_mes1.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_3_mes.bin for module amdgpu
```

Comment: If you don't have a specific AMD GPU, it is unrelated ;-)